# Turning this double sum with Kronecker delta into a single sum - am I correct?

Tags: summation, kronecker-symbol

I would be grateful if you checked my solution:

$$
\sum^{\lfloor j/2 \rfloor}_{q=0} \sum^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}_{s=0} \frac{2^{k-2s}A^{q+s}}{q!s!(k-2s)!}\delta_{j-2q,k-2s}
$$

Here $\lfloor \rfloor$ means the floor function. Due to Kronecker delta, I can write:

$$
q=s+\frac{j-k}{2}
$$

Then the double sum can be turned into a single sum:

$$
\left( \lfloor \frac{j}{2} \rfloor +1 \right) \sum^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}_{s=0} \frac{2^{k-2s}A^{2s+(j-k)/2}}{(s+(j-k)/2)!s!(k-2s)!}
$$

Is this right? Also, $s+\frac{j-k}{2}$ should always be integer, because $q$ is integer, but no such condition is specified in the original expression, so how is this ensured?

Maybe I need to modify the relation betwee $q$ and $s$ like this:

$$
q=s+\lfloor \frac{j}{2} \rfloor-\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor
$$

I should also warn you that this expression will be used in another double sum with $j$ and $k$ as indices.

Comment: The sum is zero when $j-k$ is odd. When $j-k$ is even, your approach is correct if one does not forget the condition $0\leqslant 2q\leqslant j$, which is not always satisfied from $0\leqslant2s\leqslant k$ and $2q=2s+j-k$. Thus, further restrict the sum on $0\leqslant 2s\leqslant k$ to $2s\geqslant k-j$, yielding $$\sum_{s=((k-j)/2)^+}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}.$$

Comment: @Did, but what about the case $j>k$? Should I use the conditional expression $If ~(k>j)~ then~ s_{min}=(k-j)/2~ else ~s_{min}=0$?

Comment: This is dealt with explicitely in my first comment. Note that $x^+=x$ if $x\geqslant0$ and $x^+=0$ if $x<0$.

Comment: Thank you, I was not familiar with this notation

Comment: @Did, could you please post your comment as an answer? I really want to close this question as answered

Comment: Another idea: you post this as an answer and accept it. If getting points for it bothers you, use CW.